# CSS – vertical order of elements

Tags: php, css, layout

As always, I have a "simple" question at first sight.

I have a div on my webpage containing a set of buttons (links, actually, but they serve as buttons). Simply put:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" id="1" class="link1 button">text</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="link2 button">text</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="link3 button">text</a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="link4 button">text</a>
</div>
```

Now what I need to do is to line them up in vertical order. What I mean is: normally if they appear as inline-block or inline element, they will line up horizontally one after another and when the line ends, the following link appears on the next one. The same goes for float: left.
But I need them to be in horizontal order – in other words, instead of rows, there will be columns with set height. When the column reaches the end, the following button should appear in the next column.

Is there a way to make that possible through CSS?

The only other way I can imagine is that I set a function in php or something like that but I'm not really good or knowledgeable about it. But I do have the option of putting it there so if you have this kind of solution, I'll be grateful too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe initially create a column thats floated to the left within the container, add block elements until its full, then append another column after the first column, repeat. Fully able to do this with JQuery.

Comment: As I have got, you want to have links ordered vertically, top to bottom until the end, and then the remaining links should be at the top of the second column. It's hard to have them dynamically organized. But if each link has a specified height (if links are one (or `n`) line wide), this can be calculated easily through PHP or Javascript. Have the links static height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't yet tired, but hopes it helps.

```
$link_array = array();
$link_array[] = array('Google', 'http://google.com/');
$link_array[] = array('Yahoo', 'http://yahoo.com/');
$link_array[] = array('Bing', 'http://bing.com/');

$link_per_column = 10;

foreach ($link_array as $position => $this_link)
{
    if ($position % $link_per_column === 0 && ($position === 0))
    {
        echo '<div class="column">';
        echo "<a href='{$this_link[1]}'>{$this_link[0]}</a>";
    }
    elseif ($position % $link_per_column === 0 && ($position !== count($link_array)))
    {
        echo '</div><div class="column">';
        echo "<a href='{$this_link[1]}'>{$this_link[0]}</a>";
    }
    elseif (($position === count($link_array)))
    {
        echo "<a href='{$this_link[1]}'>{$this_link[0]}</a>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "<a href='{$this_link[1]}'>{$this_link[0]}</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a useful solution since I do have a set width for my buttons. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy hearing that `:)`. It's nice to tick the check mark at top-left of my answer, meaning that your question has been answered and will no more remain in unanswered question list.